# 15.10 and GTX960

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 15.10, gpu-driver

I have ordered a GTX960 to use it under Windows 10 and Ubuntu, too.

Theoretically it is supported under both OS, but I would have some questions:

1. After a clean install, will the system offer the appropriate drivers?
2. Since Maxwell nVidia creates their GPUs to run in a quiet, fanless mode. That means while the core does not reach a specific level of heat, the fans will not turn on. Will it turn on under 3D applications? Under Windows it is known to be working, but what is the current state under Ubuntu?

What about the opensource driver which is possibly activated during live install?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea  to get the card and ask about any issues you face as you face them, yes, the card is supported and will work, but we can't deal in the hypothetical, this is not a forum but an Q & A help site, if there is not an actual problem, then, there is no good answer.

Comment: Fan control is done on the hardware level. Unless you enable coolbits, your GPU should take care of itself as far as temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your questions, specific:

1. Yes it will. If a closed source driver exist for your card Ubuntu will offer this driver for installation. Not only this but maybe other drivers too. Usually we install the recommended one.
2. This depends on the driver. For nouveau (the pre-installed open source driver) you can contact the team [via IRC or the mailing list](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/nouveau/) and ask. For the Nvidia closed source driver a [forum specific to Linux](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/board/98/linux/) exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) I will ask my question there, thanks.